# Nonmonotonic SQL queries (Finding names who only like something)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to learn SQL. I have a table (called `likes`) that looks like this:

```
|---------|---------------|
| name    | color         |
|---------|---------------|
| Jane    | Red           |
| Talia   | Red           |
| Jane    | Black         |
| Loui    | Black         |
| John    | Black         |
| Jane    | Green         |
| John    | Green         |
|---------|---------------|
```

The query is `Names who like only Black`. I tried it this way:

```
SELECT L1.name FROM likes L1 WHERE L1.color = 'Black' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT L2.name FROM likes L2 WHERE L1.name = L2.name);
```

This returns empty because eventually `Loui` will equal `Loui` in the `NOT EXISTS` sub query. However, I don't know what to change it to so it only returns `Loui`.

I can use `UNION` and everything seen in the query above but nothing else.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select name
from likes
group by name
having max(color) = min(color) and max(color) = 'Black';
```

You can use your method as well.  You need a color in the subquery:

```
SELECT L1.name
FROM likes L1
WHERE L1.color = 'Black' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT L2.name
                  FROM likes L2
                  WHERE L1.name = L2.name AND
                        L2.color <> 'Black'
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you, the second query works great. So simple too. I would use other ways to do this but due to assignment instructions, I am limited to what keywords I can have in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an anti-join.

```
SELECT L1.name
FROM likes L1
LEFT JOIN likes L2 ON (L1.name = L1.name AND L1.color != L2.color)
WHERE L2.name IS NULL
AND L1.color = 'Black'
```

This works by returning rows for the same name with a different color. In cases where there is no other color, you will get `NULL`, satisfying the condition.

Comment: Thank you, however due to assignment instructions I cannot use some of those keywords (ex. `LEFT JOIN`).

Comment: @Flow tell your instructor this is the correct way to do an anti-join :)

Comment: Haha, I will definitely bring it up. Though, I think he wants us to learn how to use `NOT EXISTS`. Thank you though. Learned new ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to find people who only like one particular color, you would do something like this, using grouping:

```
SELECT name
FROM ( SELECT L1.name, MAX(L1.Color) AS color
       FROM likes L1
       GROUP BY L1.name
       HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 ) a
WHERE color = 'Black'
```

You get a grouped result set of people-color associations. Then you filter that set and return only people with only only one association of your chosen color.

Answer (score 1):

You can do using a subselect that return the name that likes only one color and then filter by color black

```
select name fro likes
where name in      ( select name
      FROM likes 
      Group by name
      HAVING count(*) = 1 )
and color = 'Black' ;
```

Comment: Thanks, really wish I could use some of the keywords everyone is posting. Maybe it will be helpful to someone else.